# How to hide the title bar of a program (for example Notepad) using autohotkey

Tags: autohotkey

I would like to completely hide the title bar of Notepad. That means that (1) if I switch to existing instances of Notepad, the titles gets hided, (2) if I open new instances of Notepad, the titles gets hided.

I have used the following but it does not work. Any help to correct the code or another solution is welcomed.

```
#IfWinActive, ahk_class Notepad
WinSet, Style, -0xC00000, A
return
#IfWinActive
```

Comment: So you mean that you want to automatically hide the titlebar when you open notepad?

Comment: @0x464e, some explanations were added.

Comment: You need a timer and the function WinActive() in its label.

Answer (score 1):

```
#SingleInstance force
#warn

SetTimer, HN, 2500
return

r::Reload
x::ExitApp

HN:
If WinActive("ahk_class Notepad")
WinSet, Style, -0xC00000, A
return
```

Answer (score 0):

the above code works for me, just tested on win10

Comment: try to open another instance of Notepad to see what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

It will work Only If Someone Assigns a Hotkey to execute the job... Meaning Something Should Trigger It Somewhere like in the below example.

Note: In the Script below, Both y and z, would perform the same job.

```
    #SingleInstance force
    #warn
    
    r::Reload
    x::ExitApp

    #IfWinActive, ahk_class Notepad
    y::WinSet, Style, -0xC00000, A
    #IfWinActive

/*or*/

    #IfWinActive, ahk_class Notepad
    z::
    WinSet, Style, -0xC00000, A
    return
    #IfWinActive
```

Below ones too can help you further in that direction

```
If WinActive...

IfWinActive...
```

Comment: This does not answer the question, but thank you anyway.